# Windows: How can I redirect sound coming in from the mic to the speakers output

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-vista, audio

Scenario - I want to use my mic plug as a "line-in" input that will get mixed with the other audio being output to the speakers. How can this be done on Windows 7 / Vista?

Comment: There is a fatal flaw with all of the solutions offered. A PC mic jack, unless it's on a pro-level audio interface, is not a stereo input. Your mic's plug does have three contacts but the third (the "ring" in the plug) is for a +5VDC supply to a little preamp that's in the mic. So not only will connecting a "line" source to this not feed both speakers, the +5V may damage whatever you connect to it. This is also why some have reported gross amounts of noise from these attempts.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

### Windows 8.1

1. Right-click the volume-control icon in the notification area

   [image: Illustration of the volume control icon in the notification area]
2. Select *Recording devices* in the context menu

   [image: Illustration of the context menu of the volume control icon in the notification area]
3. Find your microphone in the list of recording devices

   [image: Illustration of the list of recording devices]
4. Click *Properties* and go to the *Listen* tab
5. Check the *Listen to this device* checkbox

   [image: Illustration of the Listen to this device checkbox]

### Windows 7

1. Click the volume control icon in the notification area

   [image: Illustration of the volume control icon in the notification area]
2. Click the speaker icon above the slider

   [image: Illustration of the speaker icon button]
3. In the properties dialog go the the *Levels* tab
4. Unmute the Microphone there:

   [image: Illustration of the mute button in the Speakers property dialog]

### Windows Vista

1. Go to the Control Panel
2. Click *Hardware and Sound*
3. Under *Sound* click *Manage audio devices*
4. Click *Speakers* and then *Properties*
5. In the properties dialog go the the *Levels* tab
6. Unmute the Microphone there.

Comment: I don't think those instructions will work.  Those allow the microphone to record, but unless some application is playing back what is recorded, nothing will come out of the speakers.

Comment: It definitely works here in sending what the microphone picks up to the speakers. The setting won't change the volume or mute state of the recording device. That's why it's on the *speaker's* property page.

Comment: In Windows 8.1 the microphone is missing on the Levels tab. Is that my machine thing or Windows thing?

Comment: @Septagram: I updated the answer for Windows 8.1

Comment: You're talking about 2 different things.  Your "Windows Vista" and "Windows 7" instructions are referring to hardware sidetone/direct monitoring inside the sound card, while the "Listen" feature is a software passthrough.  You should always use hardware monitoring if it is available (on any OS).  Hardware sidetone has zero latency but only works internally to one sound card/device.  Software playthrough has latency, but can connect different sound cards to each other.

Comment: And current for Windows10 too.

Answer (score 4):

Windows 7 supports this out of the box.

1. Right-click on the volume icon and select Recording Devices
2. Double-click on your microphone
3. Select listen tab
4. Check the "listen to this device" box

Comment: Should have known about that one. I even read Larry Osterman's blog ... Those two different ways we describe also seem to be orthogonal. Also my described way causes the output to be slightly more quiet. Interesting.

Comment: You're right, they're orthogonal.  Your solution requires that the manufacturer provide hardware support for the feature, Steve's solution doesn't require hardware support (thus works in more cases)

Answer (score 2):

## Windows 10

1. Right click on speaker icon on task bar
2. Open sound settings
3. Under "Input", choose your input device and click "Device properties"
4. Navigate to the "Listen" tab and check the box "Listen to this device" and choose appropriate output device

Comment: Add a step: 3.1 Under "Related Settings", click Additional device properties. This brings up the dialog for step 4.

Answer (score 0):

1. Right-click on *Soun*d.
2. Select *Recording Devices*.
3. Right-click on *Microphone* window.
4. Click on show disable devices.
5. Disable *Microphone*.
6. Enable *Stereo Mix*.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please read the question again carefully. Your answer does **not** answer the original question. Please explain how disabling the microphone allows microphone input to be redirected