# Is it possible to redirect input from a microphone to speakers and adjust the output frequency?

Tags: windows-7, audio, speakers, microphone

I have a testing device, which can check if the other device I’m developing produces sounds at the right moments (volume and frequency tests are out of scope, only timing is important). It has standard 3.5mm analog port as microphone input.

Unfortunately the testing device is unable to detect signals above 4 kHz, and the solution currently under development has emits sounds at 5 kHz.

My idea is to connect testing device’s input with laptop’s headphone output, and the microphone to laptop’s microphone input and redirect the signal at lower frequency.

I already know how to simply input to output thanks to those instructions:

- [Windows: How can I redirect sound coming in from the mic to the speakers output](https://superuser.com/questions/22347/windows-how-can-i-redirect-sound-coming-in-from-the-mic-to-the-speakers-output)
- [How to redirect audio from Microphone input in Windows 7?](http://www.abyssmedia.com/isound7/how-to-redirect-microphone.shtml)

But this only allows me to change volume, not the frequency.

What software can I use to change the signal according to my needs?

I run Windows 7 so I prefer Windows-oriented solution, but I have Fedora Linux in VirtualBox just in case if there isn’t one.