# How to redirect text-to-speech output to microphone input in Windows?

Tags: windows, audio, skype, microphone, text-to-speech

I have a lot of social anxiety involving my voice and would like to reply back to people in Skype/TeamSpeak/Discord. Using text chat isn't always an option because the people I talk to don't often look at it. I've been told I should just set my speaker output next to the microphone but that would cause a whole bunch of unwanted sounds to be picked up, like everyone else's voice and Windows sounds, etc.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Windows: How can I redirect sound coming in from the mic to the speakers output](http://superuser.com/questions/22347/windows-how-can-i-redirect-sound-coming-in-from-the-mic-to-the-speakers-output)

Comment: Not a duplicate. Asking for a program that specifically pushes text to speech through a virtual microphone and nothing else.

Answer (score 1):

I just wrote a small application for this. It serves one simple purpose only: To redirect TTS output to voice chat inputs, can be found [here](https://github.com/AsterNighT/tts-voice). It is based on edge-tts and virtual audio cables.

It is quite crude now but usable. The code is simple and you can switch to other tts implementation if you like. Let me know if there are any bugs or if you have any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Soundflower is software that will redirect TTS as a virtual microphone

http://soundflower.en.softonic.com/

Comment: Welcome to Super User, thanks for your input. Answer with link only will be considered low quality even if it helps the OP. Please follow [this outline](http://meta.superuser.com/a/5330/432690) when recommending software. You may [edit your answer](http://superuser.com/posts/1113819/edit) and make it better.

Comment: Beware: softonic.com has been known to distribute PUPs. You should link directly to github (https://github.com/mattingalls/Soundflower). In addition Soundflower is a MAC program so useless on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

(*Yes old thread*) **Voicemeeter** on Windows (I use it on 10) will allow you to define virtual devices and route output through it to your inputs.  For example you can define a virtual device to which your TTS program sends its sound, and use that as the microphone input.  It does much more, like giving a virtual mixer so you can use other inputs (playing a media file while overdubbing with the microphone) simultaneously.  It takes a bit to set up.
[Get it here](https://www.vb-audio.com/Voicemeeter/).

Comment: Please read [How do I recommend software](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/5329/how-do-i-recommend-software-in-my-answers/5330#5330) for some tips as to how you should go about recommending software. You should provide at least a link, some additional information about the software itself, and how it can be used to solve the problem in the question.

Answer (score 0):

well you can always just use textreader or a similar software near your microphone. Not the most elegant solution but hey it works.