# Redirecting Line in to bluetooth headset

Tags: windows-10, audio, bluetooth

I'm running windows 10, and I want to direct the Line in from my sound card to the output.  I can't do it via the control panel/Sound as [this example](https://superuser.com/questions/22347/windows-how-can-i-redirect-sound-coming-in-from-the-mic-to-the-speakers-output) gives due to wanting the sound to go to my Bluetooth headset.  Using the example above will force it out the speakers, not the Bluetooth.  I know I'll have to use some sort of software re-direction but I don't know if anything is available now that does that.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? n.b.: "Line in" is not something that comes "from" your sound card. It's for sending audio _to_ your sound card.

Comment: I'm trying to direct the audio from my Roku player to my Bluetooth headset.

Comment: Unfortunately, while the control panel settings for your "mic" jack commonly include a "listen to this device" (i.e. feed the sound from the mic to your speakers), the ones for "line in" devices don't. You will indeed need something like "Voicemeeter Banana" or "Virtual Audio Cable".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're trying to send *all* of your audio through your Bluetooth headset, you can just set it as the default playback device for sound instead of your computer's speakers.

Otherwise, if you want only this audio to go to your Bluetooth device and other audio to go elsewhere, you'll probably need a digital mixer (or, as you mentioned, "software re-direction"). I use [VoiceMeeter Banana](http://vb-audio.pagesperso-orange.fr/Voicemeeter/banana.htm). You'll need to set VoiceMeeter as both the default playback and recording devices anyway.

Comment: I'll check it out tonight when I get home, sorry I didn't notice the response until this morning.

Comment: Sorry it took me so long to respond, but I was able to get that solution to work.  Thanks for the help